# What's the difference between “*s” and “s” variables?

Tags: c, syntax

If I have this variable:

```
char *s = "house";
```

What's the difference if I reference to it as `*s` and `s` in other parts of my code?

Comment: `s` is a pointer.  `*s` is the `char` to which it points.

Comment: View this as “char\* s” vs “char \*s”. They are equivalent declarations and keeping the “\*” grouped with the type adds clarity. Then the questions is what is the difference between a “char\*” and “char” typed variable? The meaning of “\*var” later on varies according.

Comment: `*s` and `s[0]` are the same thing, if that helps. In this case, they are `h`, and will be until/unless `s` is changed. (The `h` should not be changed, and depending on your C implementation, may not be able to be changed, because `"house"` is a constant string literal.)

Comment: @EdGrimm so how do I refer to the string as all the characters, not just the first one?

Comment: s is pointer, *s is the memory address that s is point to.  *s is the memory address of the first character in array of character "house". So *s = s[0] = 'h'

Comment: @LocTran `*s` is the memory *at* the address that `s` points to. It isn't the address itself. Pointers are addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I refer to the string as all the characters, not just the first one?

In C, code does not directly refer to all the characters of a *string*.   `char *s` points to a single character.  By conventions of the standard C library, when that character begins a *string*, then `s` is consider to point a string, yet still only the first character of a string.  It is by inspection of that character  and the subsequent ones, up to and including a *null characters*, that code knows about all the *string*.

```
char x = *s;  // x assigned the value of the first character pointed to by s.

size_t  len = strlen(s); // len assigned the _length_ of the string 
// Length determined by walking the string until finding a null character '\0'.

// t is assigned the same pointer value as s.  Data they reference is not replicated.
// t and s both point to the same string.
char *t = s; 

char u[strlen(s) + 1];
strcpy(u, s);  // String data pointed to by s is coped to u.
```

---

In C: "A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."

Answer (score 2):

`*s` and `s[0]` are the same thing, if that helps. In this case, they are the letter `h`, and will be until/unless `s` is changed. (The `h` should not be changed, and depending on your C implementation, may not be able to be changed, because `"house"` is a constant string literal.)

If it is used in a context that expects a `char *`, `s` is the whole string. But it's important to keep in mind that it is not a constant, even though what it's initially pointing to is.

By contrast,

```
char c[] = "house";
```

declares and initializes `c` with an immutable value. You could prepend the `const` keyword to make that more clear, but that would be mere decoration. Since it's initialized with brackets, its value in the pointer sense can't be changed, and since its initial value is also a constant, that can't be changed. Note that you're only able to get away without giving a length for the array because of the assignment of the literal - the compiler can tell it is a 6 character array because of the length of the literal. If you *did* give it a length, then it would not be immutable without the `const` keyword.

Comment: "*creates c as a character array that cannot be changed.*" you probably mean the right thing, but as it stand the wording is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to a variable as `*var`, you are *dereferencing* it, i.e. the value of the statement `*var` is what `var` points to. When you refer to a variable as `var` (no `*`), you are accessing its actual content, which may or may not contain the value of a memory address containing the data you're interested in.

This can be a bit confusing for beginners since the syntax for declaring a variable as a pointer (`T *p`) uses the same operator (`*`) as the one used for dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: On the other hand, if you read it as intended, it is not confusing any more when you read the declaration as it should: `*s` i.e. "the object pointed to by `s` is a `char`"